# Strange horizontal menu problem with firefox on Mac

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox

I recently implemented a website with Contao for a partner ([www.medivas.de](http://www.medivas.de)). All is well accept one thing:
The last menu entry of the main navigation (top, above the slideshow) makes a line break. This is only with Firefox (3.6) on Macintosh, this does not happen on Linux (my development platform) nor on Ubuntu 8 and 10, nor on Windows and not with any other browser (IE, Chrome, Safari just to name the major ones). All is well so far. Problem is I can not reproduce this issue, I do not have a Mac, therefore I have to rely on other people.

Within the CSS defintion I tried to remove/changed/modified the padding (from `padding:0 5px 8px 0;` to `padding: 0;`) of the `#nav-slide-wrapper` div, because exact same problem with the line-break of the last menu entry happend with Chrome earlier in development phase. The padding is needed for the drop shadow image right and bottom of the slide show. Well, removing the padding leads to no success (my partner and another guy checked it with their firefox on mac, same issue, no change).

I have no clue, what to change, even though I can not test, like said, I own no mac.

So I would appreciate help from somebody, that has a Mac, has the firebug extension installed and has knowledge of HTML/CSS and could give me a hint how to fix this problem. Right now I am clueless, even that only the firefox on Mac seems to have this problem I am really at the end of ideas.

If more info is needed, if I forgot anything,  please let me know.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Andreas

Comment: I should mention, that i use jquery to adjust the menu item paddings (that they evenly distribute over the given width), but that should not be the problem, since it works with every browser so far. I doubt that the problem is at this point.

Comment: Just checked on FF 3.6.13 on OS X 10.5.8 and all seems fine. All navigation links are lined–up, nothing wraps.

Comment: Using https://browserlab.adobe.com I don't see any line break. Here the screenshot: http://img695.imageshack.us/f/osxff3500.jpg/

Comment: @polarblau: Thanks! I Just received the detailed info: My partner uses FF 3.6.7 and OS X 10.6.6. Are there any known problems that you might know of? @Sotiris. Thanx, I can not access imageshack.us as it might be blocked. I work from china :-) But as you notice everything seems ok.

Comment: I wouldn't know of any issues, but that doesn't mean much. I'd add `position: relative;` to `ul.nav-main-top`, but that's a shot in the dark since I can't reproduce the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to everybody so far. Now the english content is published and my partner says, the break of the last menu item happens there in the english version. I can not see any problem on the english side as well. All is lined up. Would you guys be so kind and test the english page menu too? Either go to www.medivas.de/home-en.html or click the english flag on the right hand side top corner. Once again, thanks for your help, I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using Max OSX 10.6.6 and Firefox 4b13, I don't report any line-break either.